# how to use Python script (selenium) to extract data from excel sheet and input into website

Tags: python, excel, pandas, selenium, automation

I was wondering how I would be able to get rows data from an excel spreadsheet and input it into text boxes on a cms using selenium. I was confused on how i would enter 1 row of data into 1 text box and the next row of data into the next text box.

if someone would be kind of enough to help, that would be amazing.

thank you

Comment: Could you add the actual code you used?

Answer (score 0):

you can use pandas to read an excel file and Keys from the Keys class in selenium.

this has a list of functions you can pass to interact with the browser with their unicode(? might be wrong) equivilent.

```
class Keys(object):
    """
    Set of special keys codes.
    """

    NULL = '\ue000'
    CANCEL = '\ue001'  # ^break
    HELP = '\ue002'
    BACKSPACE = '\ue003'
```

---

```
import pandas as pd
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium import webdriver



df = pd.read_excel(your_excel_file)


driver = webdriver.Chrome(your_driver)

### do stuff


data = df[your_data_col][0] # grabbing one value, you'll probably need to iterate using a loop.


driver.find_element_by_xpath(your_xpath).send_keys(data)
# do more stuff.
```